# Retorno de data, al ejecutar query

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Cuando intento almacenar la data, del siguiente codigo:

"const prueba = await con.query('select * from prueba');"

me devulve un objeto en vez de la data, cabe resaltar que este mismo proceso lo desarrolle en otro proyecto en el cual me corria, y devolvia normalmente.

Fraccion del codigo que me retorna al hacer console.lo(prueba):

```
" Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    error: [Function (anonymous)],   
    packet: [Function (anonymous)],  
    timeout: [Function (anonymous)], 
    end: [Function (anonymous)]      
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error
      at Protocol._enqueue (E:\Worpace\SullanaExpress\backSullana\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
      at Connection.query (E:\Worpace\SullanaExpress\backSullana\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
      at getAllIncidents (E:\Worpace\SullanaExpress\backSullana\src\database\incident.js:7:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Worpace\SullanaExpress\backSullana\src\database\incident.js:30:1)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18),"
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Al ejecutar "const prueba = await con.query('select * from prueba');" esta linea de codigo, espero como respuesta la data de la tabla prueba, pero en vez de eso, me retorna un objeto